# Is there a way to call a deferred implementation in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, deferred

I'm not sure if the terminology is exactly correct here.

I have a class with some static methods that are called by several other classes in some library code written long ago.

The class with the static methods that are called by several other classes has a reference to a third party class that now has a version 2.

Is there a way I can code this class to do something like "when this static method is call, there will be something that you need to call to see which version of the library you should be using"?

Such that when I pull this library code in to a new project as a jar file, I can include something in each project that will tell my class in the library with the static methods to use a specific version.

Such that I don't need to provide a version1 and version2 of each of the classes in my library.

Am I on the right track with deferred?

A lambda function maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. Java doesn't load a class unless you actually need it. This means you can do something like this:

```
public String getFoo() {
  switch (versionRequired()) {
    case 1: return new Version1Impl().getFoo();
    default: return new Version2Impl().getFoo();
  }
}

boolean versionRequired() {
  // figure out which version is needed here.
  // if you're having trouble with this, you can use `Class.forName` to check
  // if a certain type is even available. Worst case scenario, you can
  // ask a class for its own bytecode and hash that. This is very tricky.
  return 1;
}

private static class Version1Impl {
  public String getFoo() {
    return new UseSomethingFromV1().getFoo();
  }
}
```

The clue with the weird 'redirect to an inner class' stuff here is that the inner class won't be loaded until the switch branch is taken, and as long as e.g. `Version2Impl` never loads, you also never get the error that it is referring to a class that doesn't exist (because it was designed for v2 of that library, but only v1 is available).

---

NB: About that version detection scheme: The problem with hashing classes is that a class may not have changed between 2 major releases (you wanted it to be different but it will not be). Or, on the flip side, a minor point release update may have changed it (it is now different, but you did not want it to be). One solution is to hash a lot of classes, which helps with the first case (you want to notice changes), but makes the second worse. You can do this with e.g. `try (InputStream in = String.class.getResourceAsStream("String.class")) {` - which works for any class. Toss this inputstream through a hasher (search the web if you don't know how, this is a *very* common task, plenty of tutorials to find).

Many libraries have a supported way to ask them what version they are, but there is no standard, so check the docs of this library.

Comment: I like it.  The versions I am dependent on do come in different jars.  So for each project I could include only the jar with the correct version.  In the unlikely case that two versions were packaged in the same jar, I'd be kind of stuck on the "// figure out which version is needed here."  But since I can include only the jar with the correct version, I can dynamically load a class know to only be in the jar for that version to check which one is being used.  Thanks!

Comment: Possibly if both are available, just load the v2 impl.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different solutions to your problem, depending on how your third-party library has changed.

I'm assuming version 2 of your third-party class has new methods that are not on version 1 that you need?

The simplest solution is to implement your class against version 2 of the library, but handling [LinkageError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) (or more a more specific subclass, for instance [NoSuchMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)), and reverting to version 1 calls if these errors are caught. You can also handle if it's a completely different class, by handling [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html).

Alternatively, if performance isn't critical, you can also use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've created a file based solution.  Look for a file on the class path, if it is there, read what version is indicated from the file. If there is no file, use the default (original) version.

```
package com.nach.core.util.fhir.parser;

import java.io.File;

import org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.api.IBaseResource;

import com.nach.core.util.file.FileUtil;

import ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext;
import ca.uhn.fhir.parser.IParser;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class FhirJsonParser {

    private static final FhirContext CTX;
    
    private static final IParser PARSER;

    static {
        File fhirContextFile = FileUtil.getFile("/fhir-context.txt");
        if (fhirContextFile != null && fhirContextFile.exists()) {
            String fhirContext = FileUtil.getAsString(fhirContextFile).trim();
            if ("Dstu3".equals(fhirContext)) {
                log.info("USING DSTU3 FOR FHIR PARSING");
                CTX = FhirContext.forDstu3();
            } else if ("R4".equals(fhirContext)) {
                log.info("USING R4 FOR FHIR PARSING");
                CTX = FhirContext.forR4();
            } else {
                CTX = FhirContext.forDstu3();
            }
        } else {
            CTX = FhirContext.forDstu3();
        }
        PARSER = CTX.newJsonParser();
    }

    /**
     * Generate a class from a json string.
     */
    public static <T extends IBaseResource> T parse(String jsonString, Class<T> cls) {
        try {
            IParser parser = CTX.newJsonParser();
            parser.setStripVersionsFromReferences(false);
            CTX.getParserOptions().setStripVersionsFromReferences(false);
            IParser jsonParser = CTX.newJsonParser();
            T rtn = jsonParser.parseResource(cls, jsonString);
            return rtn;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate a json string from a class.
     */
    public static String serialize(IBaseResource resource) {
        String rtn = PARSER.encodeResourceToString(resource);
        return rtn;
    }
    
}
```